# checkbox variable in rails always true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I have a rails app where I am using a checkbox on my view to determine which part of my if statement runs. I thought this would be an easy task but even though the response in console after clicking submit button shows both: "adult"=>"0" (when not checked) and "adult"=>"1" (when checked) but if I try

```
puts @application.adult
```

the console only prints true

Here's the relevant part of my .html.haml file...this is my most recent attempt

```
=simple_form_for( :application, :url => users_partner_acceptance_path( application ), :method => :put ) do | f |
  .clearfix
    .column
      =f.input :full_name, label: 'Full Name', placeholder: 'Full Name'
      .help-block *&nbsp;please enter your legal name
      =f.input :address_1, label: 'Address', placeholder: 'Apartment, Street'
      =f.check_box_tag :adult, inline_label: 'I am over 18 years old.', as: :boolean, checked = true
      .guardian
      =f.input :guardian_full_name, label: 'Guardian Full Name', placeholder: 'Full Name'
      =render 'partner_details_errors', application: application
  =f.submit 'Show Contract', class: 'btn btn-primary', data: { 'text' => 'Create Contract', 'disabled-text' => 'Creating ...' }
```

I've tried

```
{:checked=> true}
```

and

```
checked: true
```

instead of

```
checked = true
```

and probably a few others
I've tried

```
=f.check_box :adult
```

and

```
=f.input :adult
```

instead of

```
=f.check_box_tag :adult
```

In my controller, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if @application.adult == true
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

Any suggestions, help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I'm using Rails 3.2.12

Comment: check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {}) use this without using f.

Comment: also check in your model code like following: `def hobby; hobby ||= true; end;` i got the same issue when the code was in my project

Answer (score 0):

`check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})`

If adult is a part of the Application class, then you want `f.check_box` instead of `f.check_box_tag`. Otherwise, you should just have `check_box_tag...`.

`= f.label :adult, "I am over 18 years old."`

`= f.check_box, :adult`

Can you post what your `params` hash looks like when submitted? FYI you don't need to do `if @application.adult == true` since the if will already be doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean, that I don't need to have a conditional if statement? I have to have a conditional so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: If `if @application.adult` is true then that block of code will run, you don't need to explicitly check `== true`

Comment: =check_box_tag(:adult, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})   (had to add : for it to keep it from erroring but still same result as before where checkbox checked or unchecked doesn't change outcome.
I then tried it with =f.check_box, :adult (error because of comma),  =check_box :adult and =f.check_box :adult still no change.
I understand what you mean about not needing == true  I first thought you meant to get rid of the full conditional.

Comment: Does anyone have any other suggestions? Please.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= f.check_box :hobby, {:multiple => "true"}, "hockeys", nil %>`

`<%= f.check_box :hobby, {:multiple => "true"}, "cricket", nil %>`

---

This will be helpful to you.